# Proof of fundamental decomposition theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Robert ash abstract algebra book, chapter 4 pq18, in the proof of fundamental decomposition theorem, there is one line which states this 
$$M \cong R^n/K \cong \frac{\bigoplus Ry_i}{\bigoplus Ra_i y_i}$$ where $\lbrace y_1,...,y_n \rbrace$ is a set of basis for $R^n$ and $\lbrace a_1y_1,...,a_ny_n \rbrace$ is a basis for $K$.

I don understand why the second isomorphic is true. Is it because of this $R \cong Ry_i$, where $y_i$ is a basis element of the module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the following fact: if $\{x_1,...x_k\}$ is a basis for the (free) $R$-module $N$, then
$$N \cong R x_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus R x_k =:\bigoplus_{i=1}^k Rx_i.$$

Comment: May I know why the first isomorphism is true? If possible can you provide the proof of the fact?

Comment: @Idonknow What is your definition of free module? What is your definition of direct sum of modules? There is really no proof here to give, just translate the definition of *free module* in the language of direct sums.